# Issue to ingest data from SAP Cube or Calculated View in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, hana, sap-bw

I have SAP Hana connected in Azure Data Factory. I am ingesting data from SAP Cube or calculated view but in preview I get only columns(Schema) but no data. I have applied column filters but still it is not showing data in Azure Data Factory.
Can anyone help me in this? Can it has its own input parameters that we need to pass?

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons. Do you have a direct access to HANA via HANA studio or Web IDE or command line (hdbSQL)? Does `SELECT` from that view provide any data in the mentioned tools? Does your view have analytic privileges applied to it? Also you mentioned cubes, but how do you try to get the data from it: via Calculation View or via direct access to tables?

Comment: Hi @astentx, I don't have direct access to the SAP HANA system, I only have HANA connected in ADF. I am trying to fetch data from HANA Cube and I am trying to load data by selecting the Calculated View. But there is no data in output.
Can it has its own parameters that I could not see in ADF but they are required?

Comment: Yes, there can be some. You can check if there's something about parameters (also their default values) from `select * from _sys_bi.bimc_variable where cube_name = 'your calc view name'`.

Comment: Thanks @astentx, I have got the data now. SAP cube has its own parameters that are required in calculation as input and then it generates data. I got all the parameter from the query that you have shared "select * from _sys_bi.bimc_variable where cube_name = 'your calc view name'"